# Directory.GetFiles() throws exception - Folder name has spaces at the end not recognized

Tags: c#

I have a folder name that looks like this:

```
\\server\pictures\607\27022015\HARD\  //temp dir
\\server\pictures\607\27022015\HARD\550528  //dir name (two spaces behind)
macId //a string representative of a folder name (two spaces behind)
```

In my code I get the folder name by doing this:

```
if (Directory.Exists(tempDirectoryWithoutMac))
                {
                    var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(tempDirectoryWithoutMac);

                    var directoryToSearch = subDirectories.Where(c => c.Contains(macId.Trim()));

                    if (directoryToSearch.Any())
                    {
                        var newDirectory = directoryToSearch.First();

                        foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(newDirectory))
                        {
                            var retVal = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename.TrimEnd()));

                            return retVal;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If I inspect and then copy and paste the `newDirectory` into Windows Explorer it takes me to the folder; however, my code throws an exception:

```
The network path was not found.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path)
   at URM.ViewModels.CollectionsViewModel.GetImages(String macId, String type)
```

If I try to rename the folder taking out the spaces at the end...Windows says...the source and destination file names are the same.

**Edit**
I'm pasting this path (quotes used to show spaces):

"\\server\pictures\607\27022015\HARD\550528  "

Comment: which path are you pasting.. can you show that as part of your edited question..? also what line is  throwing the error.. make sure that the path has only a valid path and no file name at the end of it.. if there are spaces in a file path then you need to prefix the path variable with the `@` literal

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/738002  
Folder names with trailing spaces are not allowed.

Comment: Assuming macId is a string, is it a string with the whole file path or just the name of the directory itself? Directory.GetDirectories(string path) returns strings of the FullName of the subdirectories. If you want the names of the folders instead try creating a new instance of DirectoryInfo from tempDirectoryWithoutMac then call GetDirectories.Where("filter") this will give you a collection of DirectoryInfo Objects. If you use the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo Objects instead of their paths it be a little more reliable.

Comment: remove the space for starters also try this 
`@"\server\pictures\607\27022015\HARD\550528\"`

Comment: @CalebB macid is the name of the folder...the subdirectory of tempDIrectoryWithoutMac ...get directories returns a list of all the subfolders - the full path - as you said and then I use that full path in the call the GetFiles() - GetFiles() is what throws the exception.

Comment: Yes that is true, however if you use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo Objects instead of the plain strings you won't have that problem with spaces. Object oriented programming is the way to go.

Comment: @CalebB surely that did the trick! Can you create an answer so I can accept....

Comment: @jhar100 - I only just saw the **show 3 more comments** at the end of this question where you said it worked. I remembered a way of having spaces at the start/ end of file/folder names so answered the question based on that knowledge - I think it'd also fix your problem.

Comment: @WaiHaLee That is indeed "a" solution and some very interesting material however, going about it from a more object oriented approach instead of exploiting a sort of "hack" in windows is a much better practice. You solution may work however from reading it over I don't believe it to be the best way. :)

Comment: @CalebB, I fully agree that a 'hack' in Windows isn't the best way of doing it. Most of my answer is about *how* it can be reproduced / how it might have happened, rather than fixing it. At the *bottom* of my answer I **do** suggest enumerating through the file system entries as you suggest.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I had actually tried the alt + 0160 thing didn't work. it makes the folder name what it should be but the code never recognized it as it was in windows explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use DirectoryInfo and FileInfo Objects as appose to regular strings you will have much less whitespace issues to deal with and be able to bring about a much more object oriented, and reliable solution.

You can do this like the following:

```
DirectoryInfo tempWithoutMac = new DirectoryInfo(tempDirectoryWithoutMac);

DirectoryInfo MacID = new DirectoryInfo(macId);

DirectoryInfo wantedDir = tempWithoutMac.GetDirectories.Where(c => c.Contains(MacID)).First();

foreach (FileInfo file in wantedDir.GetFiles())

{
       var retVal = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.fullname));

       return retVal;
}
```

This is just an example so you will need to tweak it to work for you but using this concept should help you out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

It **is** possible to have characters which *appear* like spaces at the end of a file system entry (file/folder) using an [alt code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code), specifically [**`alt + 0160`**](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-create-blank-folder-names-windows):

> Using this trick, you can display a folder without a name.

...

> If you right-click the folder, select Rename and enter only spaces,  the operating system will not accept it.
>
> To remove the name and display a blank name, right-click on the folder and select Rename. Now press the Alt key and from the Numeric keypad, press 0160.

The file system treats it **not** as a 'normal' space (**`alt + 0032`**) but as a '*no break space*'. See also this link on answers.microsoft.com: "[how do I add a space in front of a folder name?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-files/how-do-i-add-a-space-in-front-of-a-folder-name/4afca476-da09-4021-a8da-7ca7614125ca)" (the asker **wants** the spaces at the *start* of the folder name so it appears first in an alphabetised list):

> Actually, the "no break space" is ALT+0160...

---

**A solution in Windows Explorer**

I think that if you rename the folder, i.e. from `"550528  "` to a temporary name (e.g. `"temp"`) then you will be able to rename it to `"550528"` (note the lack of spaces) successfully.

---

**A solution in code**

As others have said, if you [enumerate through the file system entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370) in the containing folder, you'll get the entry with the correct special characters at the end without thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer strips the extra spaces at the end of the directory input.  For example, try making a folder named "foo" somewhere, then try making a "foo   " folder (with spaces at the end).  Windows will complain that there is already a folder with that name.  Just because the explorer program accepts it doesn't make it correct.  Using spaces to make different folders is probably not the best idea.

Comment: the folder exists with the spaces...when I copy and paste with the spaces...it goes to the folder with the spaces...long story short the program that saved the files this way has been modified but it wasn't directly apparent as we didn't realize spaces were at the end...however, hundreds of photos have been saved like this so they have to be processed...