# C# DirectoryInfo FullName and FullPath can't handle trailing spaces, how to fix?

Tags: c#, path, formatting, whitespace, directoryinfo

```
string directorypath = @"C:\Folder01\Subfolder01\Next_level_Down ";

DirectoryInfo mydirectoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directorypath);
```

When the above code is run mydirectoryinfo.FullName and FullPath will cut off the trailing white space at the end of the last folder in directorypath. This seems like a bug?

This will cause a crash when I run:

```
DirectoryInfo[] mysubdirectories = mydirectoryinfo.GetDirectories();
```

As it will throw an exception "could not find a part of the path..."

I have a bunch of old folders that I am sorting and collecting data on so I need to get the DirectoryInfo on them, but some of them have been saved with white space at the end of the folder name. Rather than do a separate pass to correct folder names (which could break other connections to these folders) I was hoping on being able to get DirectoryInfo to handle the white space at the end of the folder name. If that is possible?

I have a list of directories that I've entered into a .CSV file. The paths are read into a List before being looped through to instance DirectoryInfo and run my checks, so there is no way to add more formatting that might help. I am using .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Add trailing slash if it doesn't exist? So, `if (!directorypath.EndsWith("\\")) directorypath += "\\"`

Comment: may be helpful for you (dublicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888525/directory-getfiles-throws-exception-folder-name-has-spaces-at-the-end-not-re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What also helps with such unorthodox path names not supported by the shell (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/file-folder-name-whitespace-characters) is prepending `\\?\`:

```
string directorypath = @"\\?\C:\Folder01\Subfolder01\Next_level_Down ";
DirectoryInfo mydirectoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directorypath);
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file):

> For file I/O, the "\\?\" prefix to a path string tells the Windows
> APIs to disable all string parsing and to send the string that follows
> it straight to the file system.

Comment: Is it safe to add the extended-length prefix \\?\ on any folder path? I thought it was reserved for super long folder paths?

Comment: @user1544752 Yes. I added a quote from the documentation to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how you did create a Folder with a white space at the and but if it is possible add a backslash

```
 string directorypath = @"C:\Folder01\Subfolder01\Next_level_Down \";
 DirectoryInfo mydirectoryinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directorypath);
```

If your real path looks like the code above then delete the whitespace or the backslash. I think it is not possible to create a directory with a whitespace at the end and also why to put there a white space?
The last possible solution for your problem, that comes to my mind, is that the path is wrong. Somewhere in the middle is a character not correct, so that this exception will be thrown.
I hope i could help you

Comment: The real path looks similar, but much longer. These folders came from someone who was doing things on an Apple and not paying attention to their white space, so there are a bunch of these folders, with spaces at the end, scattered about a convoluted hard drive I'm dealing with. I did double check the folder paths and I'm certain it's a white space at the end. I wont even go into all the special characters they were using in their folder paths. :( ) Thanks for the help.